# requesting unread messages from google reader objective c

Tags: html

I am creating an Iphone app and I am trying to send a get request to access google readers unread messages. So far I have captured SID, Auth, and Token through the api but I dont how to do the next step of getting the unread list feed. I am new to api and I have been trying all kinds of combinations of get requests the I found online. Can some one please help by showing me some code that works for getting the unread messages from google reader. Below is one example I have tried

```
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/user/-/state/com.google/reading-list"];
httpReq = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]autorelease];
[httpReq setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"T=%@", token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Token:"];
[httpReq setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSData *recieveData;
recieveData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:httpReq returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:recieveData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"message %@", responseStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no official API for Google Reader as of yet, your best bet is projects like this http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI which attempt to reverse entineer the application. Keep in mind that anything you build could be broken if Google changes something.